# Need a projection like Azimuthal Equidistant (AEQD), but with polar coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, rasterio, reprojection-mathematics

I have a geotiff in a simple `latlon` projection. I want to reproject its data on a plane tangential to Earth ellipsoid to make some further calculations.

Just now I'm using `aeqd` projection for it, but I'm looking for some similar projection that would give me not cartesian, but **polar** coordinates.

To reproject my geotiff raster I'm using `rasterio.reproject(...)` to convert my geotiff data (it's a good analog of `cs2cs` utility from `PROJ.4`):

```
dst_crs = CRS({"proj": "aeqd", "lat_0": lat_center, "lon_0": lon_center, "datum": "WGS84"})
```

`lat_center` and `lon_center` were the center of my geotiff.

`aeqd` projection gives me some raster in cartesian grid (`x_j` and `y_i` on the tangential plane):

[image]

But for my purposes it needs some extra interpolation to get the values in my polar mesh (by distance and azimuth on the tangent plane). Can you advice me some other projection?